# Spring REST API not mapping path variables correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/product/{id}-{name}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

When I perform a GET against this endpoint with "/product/1-product-name-here" I get the following error:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException

Can anyone advise what I should do to get around this problem? I assumed Spring would take anything before the first dash as the ID and anything following that as the name but this is not the case.

If I do a GET with /product/1-name it works fine. It appears to be some strange behaviour if the path variable includes a dash.

Thanks

Comment: Your `-` delimiter is an issue. Simply change url to: `"/product/{id}/{name}"` and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/product/{id:\\d+}-{name}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

You can provide regex expressions for path variables. You need to give the regex after the colon(:).

**Reference:** https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex

Answer (score 0):

Add the bound annotation @PathVariable and assign it to desired type of variable

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/{id}/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void yourMethod(@PathVariable("id") Long id,  @PathVariable("name") String  name )
{
 ...
}
```